# Visual Studio - Newtonsoft.Json Error when running Webpack

Tags: c#, visual-studio

For some reason, whenever I try to run anything in the Task Runner in Visual Studio (specifically a compilerconfig task using Web Compiler), I get the following error inside of the Task Runner window.

> c:\users\william.yeack\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1>
>   C:\Users\william.yeack\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions\hh5zvap1.teh\WebCompiler.exe
>   "c:\users\william.yeack\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\compilerconfig.json"
>   Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.    at
>   WebCompiler.ConfigHandler.GetConfigs(String fileName)    at
>   WebCompiler.Program.GetConfigs(String configPath, String file)    at
>   WebCompiler.Program.Main(String[] args) Process terminated with code
>   -532462766.

This same error happens when I create a brand new solution. What is going on?

If I manually place the correct Newtonsoft.Json.dll into the directory containing WebCompiler.exe, it works. So why isn't it working by default?